When is the derivative of Hamilton flow respect to initial conditions independent of time?
Consider a Hamiltonian system with coordinates $\Gamma^A=(q^i,p_i)$ and let $X^A(s,\Gamma_0)$ be the Hamiltonian flow (i.e. a solution to Hamilton's equations) parametrized by time $s$ and initial conditions $X^A(0,\Gamma_0)=\Gamma^A_0$. Let me define the pushforward
$$M^A_{\ \ \  B}=\frac{\partial X^A(s,\Gamma_0)}{\partial \Gamma_0^B}.$$
My question is: In which situations does it hold that $M^A_{\ \ \  B}$ is independent of time $s$? What can we say about it? Is it related to the symmetries/conserved quantities of the system?
Examples:

Consider a Hamiltonian system with action-angle variables $(\theta,J)$. The Hamiltonian flow is $X^A=(\omega s+\theta_0,J_0)$. In this case, it holds that the pushforward $M^A_{\ \ \  B}$ is independent of $s$.
Consider now coordinates $(x,p)$ under a uniform gravitational field with acceleration $g$. The Hamiltonian flow is $X^A=(x_0+p_0 s +\frac{1}{2}gs^2,p_0+g s)$. In this case most components of $M^A_{\ \ \  B}$ are independent of time, but we see that the dependence of the position $x(s)$ with respect to initial momentum $p_0$ still depends on time $s$.


What is the $s$-derivative of $X^A$? Next use Schwarz's theorem...
